# how to remove read more after call the_content function in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to remove read-more link after calling the_content() function of wordpress. I want only to show content of each post in a loop and read-more link is redundant.

I try this code but read-more link remains after post content:

```
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'disable_more_link', 10, 2 );

function disable_more_link( $more_link, $more_link_text ) {
    return;
 }
```

where I can find the code that adds this read-more link after the content?

Comment: I don't think wordpress add read more by itself when you call `the_content()`. Are you sure you are not actually putting it explicitly in the code?

Comment: yes. I am sure.  I finally find that an excerpt plugin was installed on this site which was responsible for creating this read more link and I change setting and everything fixed

Answer (score 2):

```
    You can use a filter to remove the read-more link from content. I have updated your filter. Please try it, It's working fine.

    function disable_more_link( $link ) {
        $link = preg_replace( '|#more-[0-9]+|', '', '' );
        return $link;
    }
   add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'disable_more_link', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

[More info](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More)

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
    return '...';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```